# sagemaker endpoint invocation randomly throws error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker, mlflow

Env:

- XGBoost model trained on static data (excel).
- Model Saved and deployed to Sagemaker with MLFlow.
- Sagemaker Model and Sagemaker Endpoint are running.

Invocation:
 - I invoke the model with new data via REST Request (POSTMAN) and via boto3.sagemaker

```
client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName="xxxxxxx",
    Body=data,
    ContentType="application/json",
    Accept="string",
)
```

Problem:
It seems that Sagemaker randomly (~50% of the time) fails with following Exception:

```
{
"ErrorCode": "CLIENT_ERROR_FROM_MODEL",
"LogStreamArn": "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/xxxxxxxx",
"Message": "Received client error (400) from mfs-xxxxxxxxx-model-dztwabjotscyoc-zx7lzyfg with message \"{\"error_code\": \"BAD_REQUEST\", \"message\": \"Encountered an unexpected error while evaluating the model. Verify that the serialized input Dataframe is compatible with the model for inference.\", \"stack_trace\": \"Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\\"/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/scoring_server/__init__.py\\\", line 196, in transformation\\n    raw_predictions = model.predict(data)\\n  File \\\"/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/xgboost.py\\\", line 198, in predict\\n    return self.xgb_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(dataframe))\\n  File \\\"/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py\\\", line 1443, in predict\\n    self._validate_features(data)\\n  File \\\"/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py\\\", line 1862, in _validate_features\\n    data.feature_names))\\nValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81'] ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85']\\ntraining data did not have the following fields: 83, 85, 84, 82\\n\"}\". See https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=eu-central-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/xxxxxxxxx in account xxxxxxxfor more information.",
"OriginalMessage": "{\"error_code\": \"BAD_REQUEST\", \"message\": \"Encountered an unexpected error while evaluating the model. Verify that the serialized input Dataframe is compatible with the model for inference.\", \"stack_trace\": \"Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\\"/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/scoring_server/__init__.py\\\", line 196, in transformation\\n    raw_predictions = model.predict(data)\\n  File \\\"/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/xgboost.py\\\", line 198, in predict\\n    return self.xgb_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(dataframe))\\n  File \\\"/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py\\\", line 1443, in predict\\n    self._validate_features(data)\\n  File \\\"/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py\\\", line 1862, in _validate_features\\n    data.feature_names))\\nValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81'] ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85']\\ntraining data did not have the following fields: 83, 85, 84, 82\\n\"}",
"OriginalStatusCode": 400
```

}

After this Exception, i hit again "Send Request" in Postman (with the exact same Body Data) and get a successful response:

```
[
0.9989840388298035
]
```

The problem is exactly the same (randomly) when using boto3.sagemaker either in AWS Lambda or locally when testing.

**UPDATE 1:**
When i load the exported function with mlflow.xgboost.load_model() and run the prediction, it works everytime. Here is the code:

```py
    import mlflow
    from mlflow import xgboost
    from xgboost import DMatrix
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    base_path = "src/models/"


    model_path_name_a = f"{base_path}/model_a"
    model_path_name_b = f"{base_path}/model_b"
    # xgboost.log_model(xgb_model_a, artifact_path='https://mlflow-server-tracking.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')
    xgb_model_a = xgboost.load_model(model_path_name_a)
    xgb_model_b = xgboost.load_model(model_path_name_b)

    X_test = DMatrix(
        np.array(
            [
                [7.60000e+01, 2.57000e+02, 9.25200e+03, 2.00400e+03, 0.00000e+00, 1.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 1.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00]
            ]
        )
    )


    ############# Prediction Model A ################
    y_predA = xgb_model_a.predict(X_test)
    print(f"y_predA: {y_predA}")

    ############# Prediction Model B ################
    y_predB = xgb_model_b.predict(X_test)
    print(f"y_predA: {y_predB}")
```

Does that mean that the problem is with Sagemaker Inference/Endpoint Service?

Comment: This is probably an error with the content of the body (error 400). You need to debug the app and find what piece of data is causing the issue.

Comment: By the app you mean probably "mlflow" because it's ultimately the source code that tries to use the data on xgboost?

Comment: If that is what you are using, try to check the logs. It should probably output them somewhere.

Comment: It seems to point to the official core parackage of xgboost (see "original message" in the Exception above)

    "File \\\"/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py\\\", line 1862, in _validate_features\\n    data.feature_names))\\nValueError: feature_names mismatch:"

Comment: Seems like an XGBoost problem..https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1238#issuecomment-244414096